# Are these long 5525 barrel jack proprietary?

Tags: connector

I have tried to connect a 12v DC adaptor and also a battery pack to my telescope unsuccessfully. Sadly it seems Celestron DC jack needs to be around 2mm longer than common 5525 DC ports.
I was wondering what are **those long ports are called** and if Celestron is using an uncommon port to make customers buy its products or there is a technical reason for that?

Celestron DC5525 connector with ~14mm head.

[image]

Celestron DC5525 connector with 10mm head

[image]

[image]

Comment: (plugs are mobile, jacks aren't)

Comment: if you are going to order a replacement connector to replace that one, then first use a box cutter blade to slice off a ring off the plastic covering ... you may not need to order a replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different lengths are required because products may have different case thicknesses. The barrel jack is mounted on the PCB, flush with the edge. The plug must penetrate first the thickness of the plastic case, then enter the jack. Your Celestron probably has a nice, thick sturdy enclosure rather than the thin plastic case on cheap gadgets. That's why the most common plug doesn't seem to work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I was a nice explanation for that. But as this is very uncommon I have difficulty finding suitable cable and jack for it as well

Answer (score 2):

all barrel jacks are equally "proprietary": they're not standardized (other than people telling other people what the dimensions are).

I've seen these longer barrel connectors on quite a few products.

Answer (score 1):

They're called "barrel jacks".

Between pin diameter, outside diameter, and length, there's a gorillion combinations available, which pretty much means you'll waste an hour figuring what the right 5 cents part you actually need. Digikey sells 7 different lengths just for your 55mmOD / 25mmID.

Here are [some examples](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/barrel-power-connectors/435?s=N4IgjCBcoEwBxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzHAOxwAMdIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CYAJwBWGIhApIGHAWJkQ0gCx1ZzNp0g9%2BwsZJABaBdCVR%2BAV3UlI5fSxAcuEiwDZFAgAmXDKyFCCGXLyCohEg7ACerLhcgdgo4uJAA).

Comment: Use a drill-bit set with 0.5 mm sizes to figure out the inside diameter (ID) of the plug. Use a calipers for the outside.

Comment: Yes, in the question title I had mentioned "barrel jacks". I was after the name of the long one. so I can google it.

Answer (score 1):

5525 barrel plugs come in a wide range of mating pin lengths with different current ratings.

CUI was a major creator of these custom sizes for their power supply line of products.

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cui-devices/PP3-002BH/2197312  (14 mm)

Comment: Also, bonus trap for the unwary, there are variations of the 5.5mm jack/plug with 2.1mm and 2.5mm pin. Both versions being fairly common, and hard to tell apart by casual inspection. It is possible to put the 5.5mm x 2.5mm ID plug into a jack with a 5.5mm x 2.1mm pin, and it might appear to work but will cut out intermittently due to not enough interference for the spring contact. (had the frustrating task of supporting different products using both of these with similar voltages)